# trouble shooting bringing up oracle enterprise manager outside its linux vm

Tags: linux, oracle, virtual-machine, oracle-enterprise-manager, oracle-enterprise-linux

I received an VM with Oracle installed (VM Workstation compatible). It is installed on centOS. I can bring up sqldeveloper outside it and select data correctly when the VM is running. What I can't do is figure out how to access enterprise manager.

1 - I looked at this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e10897/em_manage.htm#BABHJAGE and found my portlist.ini file which looks like this (yes maximo is installed also):

```
Enterprise Manager Console HTTP Port (orcl) = 1158
Enterprise Manager Agent Port (orcl) = 3938
Enterprise Manager Console HTTP Port (maximo75) = 5500
Enterprise Manager Agent Port (maximo75) = 3938
```

Now when I try to bring up EM from outside the VM (like I do apps that are running on it otherwise besides EM) using this url:

```
http://192.168.174.123:5500/em
```

I get this:

> This page can't be displayed
>
> - Make sure the web address http://192.168.174.123:5500 is correct.
> - Look for the page with your search engine.
> - Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Now I can bring up another app running on the vm like this:
http://192.168.174.123/maximo

So I know the VM is running and because I can also use sqldeveloper I know the database is up and running.

Turning Windows firewall off (yes windows 7 hosting the VM) does not change the symptoms.

I can do what I want through sql, but I'd rather be able to use EM.

Can someone suggest what I'm missing or how to fix this?

Comment: Check that EM is running by executing the command `emctl status dbconsole` from the OS shell. Can you access the page through a web browser running on the server itself?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the services that should run for you database console? For that, login to the vm, set your environment and issue `emctl start dbconsole` It complains if it is already running, or start the console if it was not running, if you are lucky. Once it runs, you can connect to it using a browser.